# Como preencher um array de outra classe em JAVA

Tags: java, array

Galera, criei um metodo dentro de uma classe que busca RS no banco de dados, ela funciona perfeitamente, mas quando uso ela em outra classe, ela nao faz o desejado, veja o metodo:

```
    public void preencherArrayCidades(ArrayList acidades) throws SQLException{  
con = Conectar ();

 String sqlStmt = "SELECT * FROM Trabalho01.cidades ORDER BY nome_cidade";  
 PreparedStatement stmt =con.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
 stmt.execute(); 
    ArrayList cidades = new ArrayList(); 
 while(rs.next()){  
cidades.add(rs.getInt("id_cidade"));

}  

}
```

Para pegar esses valores, estou usando esse code:

```
    CidadeController cidadecontroller = new CidadeController();
Cidade cidade = new Cidade();
 ArrayList cidades = new ArrayList(); 
        try {
           cidadecontroller.preencherArrayCidades(cidades);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CidadeView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, cidades);
```

Answer (score 1):

`cidades.add(rs.getInt("id_cidade"));` está adicionando um inteiro dentro do array de cidades, o certo é adicionar uma cidade.

```
Cidade cidade = new Cidade(rs.getInt("id_cidade"));
cidades.add(cidade);
```

Voce deve ter um construtor na classe cidade que recebe um inteiro.

e seria mais conveniente criar um método chamado listarCidades no lugar de preencherArrayCidades

```
public List<Cidade> listarCidades(){
   List<Cidade> cidades = new ArrayList();
   //lista as cidades adiocionando na lista de cidades
   return cidades
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vendo a assinatura do seu método:

```
public void preencherArrayCidades(ArrayList acidades)
```

ele recebe um *ArrayList* que deve ser preenchido com o resultadoda *query* no entanto o que você está a fazer é criar um novo array para receber esse resultado.

Altere o método assim:

```
public void preencherArrayCidades(ArrayList acidades) throws SQLException{  
     con = Conectar ();

     String sqlStmt = "SELECT * FROM Trabalho01.cidades ORDER BY nome_cidade";  
     PreparedStatement stmt =con.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
     stmt.execute(); 
     while(rs.next()){  
         acidades.add(rs.getInt("id_cidade"));
    }  
}
```

Dessa forma é o *ArrayList* que é passado que é preenchido.

Uma outra forma é o método retornar o *ArrayList* preenchido:

```
public ArrayList preencherArrayCidades() throws SQLException{  
     con = Conectar ();

     String sqlStmt = "SELECT * FROM Trabalho01.cidades ORDER BY nome_cidade";  
     PreparedStatement stmt =con.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
     stmt.execute(); 
     ArrayList cidades = new ArrayList(); 
     while(rs.next()){  
         cidades.add(rs.getInt("id_cidade"));
    }  
    return cidades;
}
```

Depois é utilizar assim:

```
CidadeController cidadecontroller = new CidadeController();
Cidade cidade = new Cidade();
ArrayList cidades;
try {
    cidades = cidadecontroller.preencherArrayCidades();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CidadeView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, cidades);
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe algo sutil acontecendo e tem relação com os conceitos de passagem de parâmetro por referência e passagem de parâmetro por valor. Note que, embora possa paracer confuso, Java só tem passagem de parâmetro por valor, seja o parâmetro do tipo primitivo ou um objeto.

O método abaixo está recebendo uma referência para o tipo ArrayList.

```
public void preencherArrayCidades(ArrayList cidades)
```

Ao chamá-lo, o Java faz uma **cópia** da referência da variável externa ao método para o parâmetro **cidades** do método. Veja o código abaixo:

```
ArrayList cidades = new ArrayList();
cidadecontroller.preencherArrayCidades(cidades);
```

Portanto, o Java copia a referência da variável **cidades** criada fora do **preencherArrayCidades** para o parâmetro **cidades** declarado neste método.

Entretanto, dentro do método **preencherArrayCidades**, você cria outro ArrayList, sobrescrevendo a referência que o parametro **cidades** estava apontando. Aí está o problema, já que essa referência não será refletida na variável **cidades** externa ao método **preencherArrayCidades**. Lembre-se que foi feita uma cópia da referência.

Em outras palavras, ao fazer isso, a sua variável **cidades** externa ao método continua apontando para um ArrayList vazio (criado fora do método). E o parametro **cidades** do método está agora apontando para um outro ArrayList, este preenchido com os dados.

Faça como sugerido pelo @ramaral e @Skywalker. Faça um método que retorne um ArrayList e não um método que receba um ArrayList como parametro.

Caso você não queira mudar, então basta não instanciar um ArrayList dentro do método **preencherArrayCidades**. Lembre-se que a referência copiada para o parâmetro **cidades** é de um ArrayList recém criado fora do método **preencherArrayCidades**.