# Porque o retorno da função recursiva não está sendo usado?

Tags: java, array, recursão, referência, return

O que acontece quando eu chamo uma função, recursivamente, sem atribuir o retorno dela a uma variável? Por que não há a necessidade, neste caso, de atribuir a função `mergeSort` explicitamente a variável *array*?

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] array, int inicio, int fim) {
        if (fim <= inicio) {
            return array;
        }
        int meio = (inicio + fim) / 2;
        mergeSort(array, inicio, meio);
        mergeSort(array, meio + 1, fim);
        int[] A = new int[meio - inicio + 1];
        int[] B = new int[fim - meio];
        for (int i = 0; i <= meio - inicio; i++) {
            A[i] = array[inicio + i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= fim - meio - 1; i++) {
            B[i] = array[meio + 1 + i];
        }
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int k = inicio; k <= fim; k++) {
            if (i < A.length && j < B.length) {
                if (A[i] < B[j]) {
                    array[k] = A[i++];
                } else {
                    array[k] = B[j++];
                }
            } else if (i < A.length) {
                array[k] = A[i++];
            } else if (j < B.length) {
                array[k] = B[j++];
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque `array` é um tipo por referência. Tipos por referência passados como [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) de métodos se confundem com o parâmetro. Ao contrário dos tipos por valor em que uma cópia do objeto (do valor) é feito na passagem do argumento para o método, neste tipo a cópia é a penas da referência, o objeto permanece o mesmo.

Então qualquer alteração que faça no parâmetro recebido se refletirá no argumento. Você não está alterando uma cópia e sim o que foi passado, por isso o retorno é desnecessário.

O retorno só seria necessário se a classificação fosse feita em outro *array*, como ele está sendo feito *in-place* (no mesmo *array* passado), o retorno é redundante. Eu particularmente tornaria este método com retorno `void`.

Tem [mais informações sobre referência em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83481/101).

Comment: Eu até tento responder rápido, mas ser mais rápido que você é quase impossível @bigown. Que horas você dorme mesmo? :-)

Comment: Eu nem tava aqui qdo foi perguntado :)

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece, pois a variável **array** é do tipo **int[]**. Isso é um vetor e todo vetor em Java é um objeto. Dessa maneira, sempre que você chama a função **mergeSort** de maneira recursiva como exibido abaixo, a referência desse vetor é passada ([via passagem por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83512/3084)) para a próxima chamada recursiva.

```
mergeSort(array, inicio, meio);
```

Em outras palavras, você está manipulando sempre o mesmo vetor na memória. Você nem mesmo precisa retorná-lo no fim da função.